# Stuck in loop making war game

Tags: java

I'm making a war card game. I'm only supposed to use one class. When I run this it assigns `card1` and `card2` values properly, runs the loops and prints fine, but it only assigns RNG values once and I need it to break the loop and reassign values each time until someone wins.

I tried breaking it but that only ends the entire code. I'm not looking for an answer, just some input and help. It should play a hand, deduct one point from the loser add to the winner, unless it's a tie. Then it runs War and deducts 3 and adds 3 instead (for the amount of cards used). One hits zero, the game stops and the winner is printed.

```
import java.util.Random;          

public class warGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String p1 = "Player 1";
        String p2 = "Player 2";
        int s = 10;
        int p1Score = s;
        int p2Score = s;
        Random card = new Random();
        int card1 = card.nextInt(14);
        int card2 = card.nextInt(14);
        int t = 1;
        int war1 = card.nextInt(14);
        int war2 = card.nextInt(14);
        System.out.println("Let's play War!");

        //Do while loop that runs the entirety of the program inside.
        do {
            System.out.println("Turn " + t++ + " -- Player 1's card: " + card1 + " Player 2's card: " + card2);

            //determines cards, calculates values and runs proper loop
            if (card1 > card2) {
                System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
                p1Score += 1;
                p2Score -= 1;
                System.out.println("Scores -- " + "Player 1: " + p1Score + " Player 2: " + p2Score);
            } else if (card1 == card2) {
                System.out.println("Time for war!");
                System.out.println("Player 1's war card is: " + war1 + " Player 2's war card is: " + war2);
                if (war1 > war2) {
                    System.out.println("Player 1 wins the war!");
                    p1Score += 3;
                    p2Score -= 3;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Player 2 wins the war!");
                    p1Score -= 3;
                    p2Score += 3;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
                p1Score -= 1;
                p2Score += 1;
                System.out.println("Scores -- " + "Player 1: " + p1Score + " Player 2: " + p2Score);
            }
        } while (p1Score > 0 && p2Score > 0);

        //The following will print out the winner and end the game. 

        if (p1Score == 0) {
            System.out.println("Player 2 wins the game!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Player 1 wins the game!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the loop to have different outcomes, you need to provide it with different values.

When you do:

```
int card1 = card.nextInt(14);
int card2 = card.nextInt(14);
int war1 = card.nextInt(14);
int war2 = card.nextInt(14);
```

You're assigning random values to those four variables. However, these values are never changed.

I would replace these lines with:

```
int card1;
int card2;
int war1;
int war2;
```

And then:

```
do {
    // update card values
    card1 = card.nextInt(14);
    card2 = card.nextInt(14);
    war1 = card.nextInt(14);
    war2 = card.nextInt(14);

    System.out.println("Turn " + t++ + " -- Player 1's card: " + card1 + " Player 2's card: " + card2);
```

This time the variables' values will be different on each iteration.

Comment: Yeah that's it. Thank you, god I feel dumb. Guess that's a part of the learning process haha

Comment: Hi @SplendaMan if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer actually:
You assign the values of the cards outside your do-while loop. That means those values will never change unless you change them inside the loop.